# PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I am aware that these two things operated in different locations how ever I am wondering if there is anyway to include a little bit of php in my java script file
I need to generate unique url's to link to profiles and news posts. i.e /#/news/IDHERE and /#/profile/IDHERE Below I have included the script that build's my navigation for me

```
// create the module and name it scotchApp    
var scotchApp = angular.module('RoutingApp', ['ngRoute']);  

// configure our routes    
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {  
    $routeProvider  
  //Routes for HH TAB!!!
    // route for the home page    
        .when('/', {  
        templateUrl: 'staff/staff/_frontend/news.php',  
        controller: 'mainController'  
    })  

    // route for the about page    
    .when('/about', {  
        templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',  
        controller: 'aboutController'  
    })  

    // route for the team page    
    .when('/team', {  
        templateUrl: 'pages/test/test.html',  
        controller: 'teamController'  
    }) 

    // route for the Job page    
    .when('/job', {  
        templateUrl: 'pages/test/test1.html',  
        controller: 'jobController'  
    }) 

    // route for the FAQ page    
    .when('/faq', {  
        templateUrl: 'pages/test/test2.html',  
        controller: 'faqController'  
    }) 

    // route for the Complaint page    
    .when('/complaint', {  
        templateUrl: 'pages/test/index.php',  
        controller: 'complaintController'  
    })

//Routes for Radio Player
    // route for the request page
         .when('/request', {  
        templateUrl: 'pages/requestline.php',  
        controller: 'requestsController'  
    })  

 // route for the Register page 
        .when('/register', {  
        templateUrl: 'pages/register.php',  
        controller: 'registerController'  
    })

});  

//comtrollers for HH TAB  
// home   
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {     
    $scope.HomeMessage = 'Home Controller Called !!!';  
});  

//About
scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {  
    $scope.AboutMessage = 'About Controller Called !!!';  
}); 

// team
scotchApp.controller('teamController', function($scope) {   
    $scope.teamMessage = 'team Controller Called !!!';  
});  

//jobs
scotchApp.controller('jobController', function($scope) {  
    $scope.jobMessage = 'Jobs Controller Called !!!';  
}); 

//faq
scotchApp.controller('faqController', function($scope) {  
    $scope.faqMessage = 'FAQ Controller Called !!!';  
});  

//complaint
scotchApp.controller('complaintController', function($scope) {  
    $scope.complaintMessage = 'Complaint Controller Called !!!';  
}); 

//controllers for radio player!!
//requests
scotchApp.controller('requestsController', function($scope) {  
    $scope.requestsMessage = 'Requests Controller Called !!!';  
}); 

//register
scotchApp.controller('registerController', function($scope) {  
    $scope.registerMessage = 'Register Controller Called !!!';  
});
```

Lets say I have a file that runs a query's here is an example of one of my pages!

```
$query = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE `category` = '13' AND `status` = '1' ORDER BY `news`.`id` DESC" );
$array = $db->assoc( $query );

while( $array = $db->assoc( $query ) ) {
    $time = date( "d/m/y ", $array['stamp'] );
    $query99 = $db->query( "SELECT habbo FROM users WHERE id = '{$array['author']}'" );
    $array99 = $db->assoc( $query99 );
    $cquery = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM news_comments WHERE article = '{$array['id']}'" );             
    $comment = $db->num( $cquery );
?>
<a href="#/news/<?php echo $array['id"];?>></a>
```

I need the url to be the same in the js file. im just not quite sure how to go about it? any help is appreciated. open to idea's on other solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of ways to go about this

You could simply change the JS files extension to .php then just output the links within the Javascript as you wished this might have the unintended side effect of messing with your IDE (as it will assume a regular php file). Alternatively you could name it something like .js.php to add some clarity but I don't know if that will solve the issue with most IDEs (it's more for your sanity)

There's plenty of other options such as using the above approach for outputting the links to an array then iterating over them in your normal JS file. If taking this approach it's probably a good idea to comment in both files why the data is being set or where it's getting it from for future reference.

Comment: So I've been looking at an example on w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_sql.asp that shows how to right a query to return like so but im not sure how to convert it to my query's

Comment: There's probably a better way of doing this actually. Route params might be what you're looking for: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams 
You'd use those to trigger an AJAX request (or request the data from a service) to return the query data. Essentially there's probably no need to store the data on the route. As for linking to those routes in your templates you would still need PHP to generate the links of course.

Comment: // route for the news page 
        .when('/news/:id', {  
        templateUrl: 'pages/news/:id',  
        controller: 'newsController'  
    })

================

//news
scotchApp.controller('newsController', function($scope, $routeParams) {  
    $scope.model = {
        message: $routeParams
    }
});

So I'm entering the url's using php and this is my js file but I can't seem to get it to work